# Python logic if and or opposite

Tags: python

```
Level = 4
Name = "Mike"
Form = None
if Level == 5 or Name in ['James','Chris','Alex'] or (Name in ['John','Mike'] and Form):
```

The above code does exactly what I want it to do, but I can't figure out how to do the opposite:

e.g.

```
if Level != 5 and Name not in ['James','Chris','Alex'] and (Name not in ['John','Mike'] and Form):
```

As close as I got but does not work the same.

Comment: Define "the opposite". I think your problem is that you don't really know what you want.

Comment: Clarify the logic you want to implement instead of just *"opposite"* that is quite broad description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about clubbing everything in parenthesis and just use `not` in the beginning. That way, you don't need to reverse any operator.

```
if not (Level == 5 or Name in ['James','Chris','Alex'] or (Name in ['John','Mike'] and Form)):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, As far as i understand it should be pretty simple,

```
if not (Level == 5 or Name in ['James','Chris','Alex'] or (Name in ['John','Mike'] and Form)):
```

another easy way would be to do something like this

```
if Level == 5 or Name in ['James','Chris','Alex'] or (Name in ['John','Mike'] and Form):
    pass
else:
    # your code here
```